# Inequalities in definitions of convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

Apparently in the following definitions (1) and (2) are equivalent and (3) and (4) are equivalent too!

1. $x_n$ converges to $x$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there's $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \ge  N$ we have $|x_n-x|< \epsilon$.
2. $x_n$ converges to $x$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there's $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n >  N$ we have $|x_n-x| \le  \epsilon$.
3. $x_n$ converges to $+\infty$ if for every $M > 0$ there's $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \ge  N$ we have $X_n > M$.
4. $x_n$ converges to $+\infty$ if for every $M > 0$ there's $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n >  N$ we have $X_n \ge M$.

The same goes for convergence to $-\infty$ etc. Why does making the inequality $n \ge N$ strict i.e. saying $n \ge N$ turn the inequality $|x_n-x| < \epsilon$ into non-strict, i.e. $|x_n-x| \le \epsilon$, turning (1) to (2) and so on?

Comment: does it? No, actually it dos not matter if you use $\lt$ or $\le$. Try to prove that all for variations of a statement are equivalent.

Comment: @miracle173 So it does not matter whether say $n \ge N$ implies $|x_n-x| \le \epsilon$ or $n>  N$ we have $|x_n-x|< \epsilon$ or indeed any of the variants I've given? Is the idea that if $N$ works then $N+1$ works; if $\epsilon$ works, then  $\epsilon/2$ works etc.

Comment: it does not mater nd I think i think you have the right idea how to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding (1) and (2), *given* epsilon, you can go back and  *pick* $N$ suitably.

Don't *pick* your epsilon - you seem to think, based on your comment above, that you can pick epsilon and then epsilon / 2.  Let epsilon be *given*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, my wording was sloppy. To think about it now, in the first case we have $ n \ge N$ implies $|x_n-x| < \epsilon$. If we replace $N$ with $N' = N+1$, then we have $n > N'$, and since $\epsilon >0$, we have $|x_n-x| < 2\epsilon$. The two changes are not tied to one another.